# AFDownloadRequestOperation - Status code 206 treated as success and corrupt file created

Tags: afnetworking

I am using AFDownloadRequestOperation. It was working fine, but is now suddenly giving this error every time I run it (I am downloading from the same URL every time I run it and I do clear the Documents and Temp folders in AppDelegate).

1. Initiate a download. (Before downloading, I do manually check that there is nothing in Temp or Documents folder, i.e. where I store the files once download is done).
2. The download gets over in 1-2 seconds, code moves to success block, the debug console shows a 206 status code, a file magically gets placed in Documents folder out of nowhere and has the exact file size (it used to get downloaded properly until I started running into this issue). The file is corrupt and does not open.

Here is the code snippet -

```
download_operation_progress_block = ^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
            float progress = ((float)totalBytesReadForFile) / totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile;
            dataFetcherObject.downloadProgressDetails.downloadPercentage = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:floorf(progress*100)];
        };
        download_operation_success_block = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            dataFetcherObject.downloadProgressDetails.isDownloadDone = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            dataFetcherObject.isDataFetched = @"Yes";
        };
        download_operation_failure_block = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [dataFetcherObject.downloadProgressDetails.downloadOperation cancel];
            dataFetcherObject.isDataFetched = @"Error";
        };

        AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:contentDownloadRequest
                                                                                         targetPath:path
                                                                                       shouldResume:YES];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:download_operation_success_block
                                         failure:download_operation_failure_block];
        [operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:download_operation_progress_block];
       // operation.deleteTempFileOnCancel = TRUE;

        NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
        dataFetcherObject.downloadProgressDetails.downloadOperation = operation;
```

What could be the reason for this.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, could not. If the caches could be cleared properly, it might help.